# I was toxic MYSELF

Tags: expressions, formal-language, informal-language, colloquial-language

I've tried looking up 'myself' but the only results I get is 'myself or by myself.' But my problem is a bit different.
I was talking about a few toxic friends who I used to play video games with and I said:

1. *"The squad broke up because of how toxic they were. But I'll admit that **I was toxic myself**."*

Is the use of 'myself' correct here? Does it mean that I'm emphasizing I was also toxic?

Another example:

2. *"Why are you yelling at me for not hearing the alarm. You didn't hear it yourself."*

If they are correct can it be used in formal situations?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both correct and suitable for formal occasions.

"The squad broke up because of how toxic they were. But I'll admit that I was toxic myself." Here you are using 'myself' correctly to emphasise or admit that you were one of the team's toxic members.

"Why are you yelling at me for not hearing the alarm. You didn't hear it yourself." - here 'yourself' is being used correctly to remind the listener that he or she is subject to the criticism they are levelling at another.

[Reflexive pronouns](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-to-upper-intermediate/reflexive-pronouns)